# Change Typesetting engine from PdfLaTeX to XeLaTex using tex file commands in Tex Live 2015

Tags: xetex, texlive

Tex Live by default loads pdfLaTeX to run the tex file. I want to change it to XeLaTeX automatically through commands in Tex file. Is there any specific command for this which I can write in the tex file? %! TEX TS-Program command doesn't seem to work with Tex Live.

Comment: texlive is a tex distribution that includes pdftex and xetex it does not default to either. I would guess that you are referring to some editor which may or may not have such a default, but you need to say which editor you are using. (I use emacs with texlive for example)

Comment: Is there any way to change that automatically through code once you have loaded the wrong typesetting engine?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by loaded. In texlive if you want to process `file.tex` with pdflatex  type `pdflatex file` on the commandline, and if you want to process it with xelatex type `xelatex file` on the commandline. there is no concept of loading one or the other.

Comment: There is no choice of doing that in an online compiler. It takes the tex file & processes it using pdflatex instead of xelatex which results in an error. That's why I'm asking if there is anything that can be done through code.

Comment: @user122472 where in your question did you mention that you are using an online compiler? Details matter. `%! TEX TS-Program` support is editor dependant, so please start over and explain what exactly you are doing.

Comment: you are asking how to configure software without saying what software you are using. How can anyone help?

Comment: If you are really using `%! TEX TS-Program = xelatex` you've got the `!` in the wrong place. It should be `% !TEX TS-Program = xelatex`. What editor are you using? What OS?

Comment: @HerbSchulz Just a minor reminder, the word _program_ in the command should be all lower case, `% !TEX TS-program = xelatex`.